# fatal: No configured push destination

Tags: git, github

Please see following screen details - git remote -v command is showing that I have test_vishwas added but when I am giving Push command it is giving error. Anybody can help ?

```
C:\Users\vishwas_gupta03\Documents\GitHub\test_Vishwas [master]> git remote -v
github  https://github.com/vishwasjione/test_Vishwas.git (fetch)
github  https://github.com/vishwasjione/test_Vishwas.git (push)
origin
C:\Users\vishwas_gupta03\Documents\GitHub\test_Vishwas [master]> git push
fatal: No configured push destination.
Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository us
ing

    git remote add <name> <url>

and then push using the remote name

    git push <name>

C:\Users\vishwas_gupta03\Documents\GitHub\test_Vishwas [master]>
```

Answer (score 26):

Try this:

`git push -u github master`

This will set your local `master` branch to track the `master` branch on the `github` remote.

Next time you push this branch, you should be able to use the shorter command `git push`.

Comment: to fix all branches at once:
git push -u github --all

Answer (score 11):

You just said `git push` without telling git what to push and where to push to. Therefore git has to *guess* what you mean.

The complete syntax for a push is:

```
git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>
```

for example

```
git push github master:master
```

which will push the current master branch to the master branch at github.

You are allowed to leave out parts, but then you need to have a good idea what the left out parts default to. (Those defaults depend heavily on you configuration.)

In your case you have defined two remotes "origin" and "github", but you did not tell git which remote it should use. Now git default to the "origin" remote. Unfortunately there is no push URL defined for that remote, hence git has no way to push to it and rightly complains about it.

You probably want to use

```
git push --set-upstream github master:master
```

This tells git to push the right thing to the right place and also sets the correct upstream for your local branch (see `git branch -vv`). Therfore a subsequent push will notice this upstream and default to the correct values.

Comment: Thanks Man was having a lot of trouble in pushing my changes due to some git issues this trick worked.

Answer (score 8):

The other answers use `git push` and require always specifying additional parameters.  This solution sets the default remote for the push operation.  The command assumes you always want to use `origin` for the remote name.

```
git remote add origin git@...com:.../...git
```

Comment: Setting the default applies only to the current repository.  Usually exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The command (or the URL in it) to add the github repository as a remote isn't quite correct. If I understand your repository name correctly, it should be;

```
git remote add my_app 'git@github.com:userName/my_app.git'
```

Now run this command

```
git push --set-upstream new master
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, and here's the way how i fixed it :

```
git branch -M main
```

after that you add a remote :

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vishwasjione/test_Vishwas.git
```

in the end you push as follow :

```
git push -u origin main
```