# Git Hub - cloaning a repo onto a local machine, but then moving and renaming the local machine's repository

Tags: git, github

If I create a local repository and then clone down the information from GitHub, can I then rename and move that local repository and it will maintain the links to GitHub and allow me to 'push' changes and 'pull' down changes others have made?  I have tried it, and it worked on one system, but not on another. The one it did not work on was a Mac, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, copying/moving repos works fine.

Comment: Can you share what git commands you used (i'm not shure I understand your setup in the first sentence)

Comment: I have a GitHub repository on the site.  On my Mac I created a directory and ran 'git init' and the 'git clone GIT HUB REPO URL'.  It seemed to work, downloading the scripts and contents to my local directory.  I changed a script file in the Mac directory and then I did 'git add .' and then 'git commit -m 'first commit'. and then 'git push' which all worked as expected. Then I moved all the contents of the Mac directory up one level and deleted the now empty sub directory.  I then tried the same experiment, 'pushing'' a change, and got this error: fatal: No configured push destination.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21072687/5340833